# Placing Tkinter Frame in another Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, frame

I am trying to experiment and get the button to only display the label when the button is clicked instead it is opening up another GUI window. The main frame is called secret message. Within this when i click onto the button it should then replace the empty place with the label in `row=2`.

Could someone explain to me how i can raise the label rather than just opening up a new window. All code is functional but i want another way around this, i am new to python.

```
from tkinter import *

def topLevel():
    top=Toplevel()
    top.geometry("300x200")

root=Tk()
root.title("Secret Message")

button1 = Button(text="Push this button to see hidden message!", width =60, command=topLevel)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)    

label1 = Label(width=50, height=10, background="WHITE", text= "There is no secret!")
label1.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to tell your widgets what container to be in. Right now they are defaulting to the root window. And how do you think the label will be displayed when you press the button? All your function is doing is opening a toplevel window. You have not even specified a frame in this example so maybe you should rewrite your question title.

Answer (score 0):

You question title has nothing to do with your question.

To update the geometry of your label you simple need to tell the function where you want the label on the container you set up your label in. In this case you do not define the container so the widgets default to the root window.

Here is a working example that will update the label geometry when you press the button.

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.title("Secret Message")

def grid_label():
    label1.config(text="There is no secret!")

Button(root, text="Push this button to see hidden message!", width=60, command=grid_label).grid(row=1, column=0)    
label1 = Label(root, width=50, height=10, background="WHITE")
label1.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am trying to get one main frame with a blank label underneath the button, when you click onto the button in the main frame, it should overlap the blank label frame underneath then add "There is no Secret!".in a new label altogether. So a Frame within a Frame, my title is fit for the purpose just unsure how to go about it, could you help with this please?

Comment: @pythonewbie I have updated my answer. Your understanding of what a frame is is not correct. What you mean is a container. A "Frame" is an actual module in tkinter that is one of the several containers.

Comment: My apologies sir, i am still learning. Next time i will try lay out my code differently.